# Immediate perscription

Tags: word-usage

`Some government only want policy they can see the effect immediately, they like an immediate prescription.`

Is the `immediate prescription` above used appropriately?

The intention is to use the metaphor `immediate prescription` to describe methods that put in place just for short-term outcome

Comment: Where is this from? Did you write it? Please give us the source.

Comment: @AIQ I wrote it

Comment: Can't figure out what the symptoms is supposed to mean.

Comment: To me **an immediate prescription** means one that is promptly *written*, rather than one with prompt *effects*.

Answer (score 1):

*Prescription* is not the right word to use here. Not sure what you're trying to get at with using the word *prescription*.

And the words *government* must have an *S* at the end to denote plural.

Written properly:
Some governments only want to implement policies whereby they would be able to see immediate results.

Comment: Yes, it is totally misused, probably literally translated from French or Spanish.